# Deleted folder keeps coming back

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash

A folder in my home folder keeps getting recreated by root (group is also root). First I tried changing the owner to my user and deleting. Then, I tried sudo rm -rf. Nothing worked.

Then I grep'ed all my disk: `sudo find / -xdev -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep -H "myuser-api-test" 2>/dev/null` for this folder's name to see if there was a script recreating it. No program was doing such thing, but still I deleted everything that referenced it and the folder still gets recreated when deleted.

When trying `rm -d` the folder, I get the following message `rm: remove write-protected directory 'myuser-api-test/'?`

It's **not** one of Ubuntu XDG folders and it's **not** on that list. At the time that I created this folder I was playing around with Docker and installing Python packages... Maybe this is connected somehow.

How do I figure out what is recreating that folder?

There was a docker container running that might be related to it. I was completely unaware that it could still be running. I haven't touched docker in months. I just stopped the container and fully removed docker from my machine. In case that doesn't work, here are further clarifications:

(1) Is its name literally m y u s e r - a p i - t e s t, or is it your user name followed by -api-test, or what? **Literally that.** "myuser" is not an user from this system.

(2) What happens if you rename it? Will try if it comes back.

(3) When you delete it, does that work? **it gets deleted. It no longer shows up when I `ls`.**

(4) Assuming that you are successfully deleting it, how quickly does it come back?  Within seconds?  Within minutes?  Next time you login?  Next time you reboot?  Can you identify anything that triggers it? **within a few seconds**, I will look for the triggers.

Comment: Any docker image running (`docker ps`)? To see if a directory is bind-mounted by a container: `docker inspect $(docker ps -aq) | grep {directory}`

Comment: (1) Is its name *literally* `m` `y` `u` `s` `e` `r` `-` `a` `p` `i` `-` `t` `e` `s` `t`, or is it your user name followed by `-api-test`, or what? (2) What happens if you rename it? (3) When you delete it, does that work? (4) Assuming that you are successfully deleting it, how quickly does it come back?  Within seconds?  Within minutes?  Next time you login?  Next time you reboot?  Can you identify anything that triggers it?   … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: You're sure its recreated instead of not being deleted?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and it turned out to be xenoid's answer.

When I went to delete folders after playing with docker and docker-compose, a few folders were being recreated with an empty node_modules directory by the root user.

The folders were being recreated by orphaned docker containers.  The containers were still running after being disconnected (from docker compose) and when I went to delete the folders they would be recreated within a few seconds.

Solution:

1. Check for running docker containers
2. If they are connected to the reappearing folders

```
docker ps
docker stop ${containerId}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this happen because of apache. Stopping it allowed me to delete the folder.

```
systemctl stop apache2
```